# Assigning and getting value from same ID name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, getelementbyid, x-editable

I'm using `x-editable` http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html a jquery inplace editor. Currently I have a working code like below:

```
<?php
    $num_rows = 1;
    // store the record of the "tblstudent" table into $row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = \"popup\";                       
        $('#username$num_rows').editable();          
        
        </script>  "; //assign num to element

        // Print out the contents of the entry
        
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="#" id="username' . $num_rows . '" data-type="text" data-pk="' . $row['id'] . '" data-url="post.php" data-title="Edit website">'; 
        echo htmlspecialchars($row['website'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        echo '</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $num_rows++;
    }
?>
```

Which result in the following:

[image]

but as you can see I use `$num_rows` in assigning element ID and getting the ID with javascript. I prefer not to use loop to assign uniq ID to element or include the javascript in php tag. Is there any elegant  solution than this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need an id ? If the intention is to know which element was clicked that can be done using jquery 'click' event.

Comment: sure, use a db ID in a data attribute so you have simple identifier to update same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the id as username or infact add `class='username'` instead of id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = "popup"; 

    $('.username').click(function(){

        $(this).editable();  

    })


</script>
```

Comment: I add both class and id `username` and it works. Thanks. My understanding of class is wrong after all.